# Tomcat - can i force NON https?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, https

I have a web app deployed in tomcat. Almost all pages in the app require HTTPS except for the index page and some others. When I acces any page that requirest HTTPS, the browser always uses HTTPS. When I access a page that do not require HTTPS the browser sometimes use HTTP and sometimes HTTPS, mostly depending on the origin.
My question is if I can force the browser to use HTTP (without the s) for those pages that do not require encryption.

Here is the part of my web.xml that decides what resources requires encryption.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Open</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/contact</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/robots.txt</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/sitemap.xml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tomcat configuration, no.

You have a number of options:

1. Write a filter to redirect those pages to HTTP
   By the time the request has reached the filter you may as well serve it. Redirecting to HTTP will result in slower response times for your users.
2. You could replace the links to the pages that do not require HTTPS with absolute HTTP links. This might be a lot of work and you need to be careful to do it in such a way that the links don't break if you change your web application's context path. It could also get messy if your server is behind a reverse proxy.
3. Live with it.

Personally, I'd go for option 3.

Comment: The problem with option 3 is that we cannot link to external resources such as CDN hosted javascript libraries on the HTTP pages. I'll figure out which option is the best for us.