# Tomcat - From HTTPS page to HTTP

Tags: java, web-services, security, tomcat, ssl

In Tomcat 8, I enabled TLS connector for secure data transmission, and I created a security constraint in my web.xml. Through the site menu, the user can go to a login page, or to the home page. Upon arriving at the login page, as I have set the security constraint, the user's browser starts a TLS communication. If the user clicks on the index menu (home), he returns to the home page, but remains an HTTPS communication. And I do not know for what reason this is happening.

Could someone tell me if this is a normal behavior of Tomcat, and if there is any possibility (not mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15569938/2910546) of another user - 2013) today (almost 2015) for this to be changed and the user returns to communicate via HTTP? For what reason redirect HTTPS to HTTP is a costly process? There is another way?

All that I find on the internet is about changing an HTTP communication to HTTPS, but that's not what I'm looking for. I already know how to do that. I'm just avoiding that when communication change from HTTP to HTTPS it stays in HTTPS even if the user try to access all the other pages of my application. I do not want that. It makes no sense for the user to access the home page with a HTTPS communication.

For me, it makes little sense Tomcat react that way. For what reason Tomcat do that? Moreover, even if things are so, for what reason Tomcat developers limit it at this point? Do the web sites today do not allow it?

**NOTE**: I am currently using Spring MVC, Tomcat 8.0.15, and Eclipse Luna Service.

Thank you for your time and attention.

---

I know that something very similar has already been asked here before:

[Tomcat - can i force NON https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564641/tomcat-can-i-force-non-https)

**Please**: Notice that there are differences in my question. I ask the moderators to read it and interpret it before simply click the close button. Furthermore, face the text as a whole, as all being the question. Do not try to go out searching for the question mark (?). I'm showing a situation.

Comment: Have you considered using HTTPS for the entire site? This is becoming more common than only using HTTPS for part of a site, and what I generally recommend to others using TLS/SSL in any capacity. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/should-all-web-traffic-be-encrypted/ for justification.

Comment: Redirect to a full URL that starts with `http://`? If you just go to a relative location (such as `/index.html`) there is little reason to change protocol. Moreover, HTTPS is HTTP over SSL, so as long as the SSL connection is up, just changing the relative URL is not going to be of much help.

Comment: Brice, the posting shows that the use of secure communication all the time can be useful ->during the work of an authenticated user<-. What is correct and commonly done in today's times. However, it makes no sense for a user to perform the logoff, or access the login page (without authentication), and then (if he wishes) go back to the home page using HTTPS. What's there to be protected? Absolutely nothing. It makes no sense at all actually. Maarten, would this be the second user-provided option of another question? That would be bad for my application, don't you think?

Comment: Why do you want HTTP over HTTPS?

Comment: @1615903 This may sound a bit rude, but believe me, I'm not being so: Did you really understand my question? Did you read the whole question and the comments made here? Or perhaps... You are not being clear on your question. What do you really want to know? I do not understand your question.